# UPDATE table WHERE other column is NULL

Tags: mysql

I'd like to update my table in that point to set an `Destroy` timestamp if there is none. The `Destroy` timestamp is defined as 5-10 days more than `Created`.

**decayworld:**

```
+------------+---------+
| Created    | Destroy |
+------------+---------+
| 1515765721 |    NULL |
| 1515765743 |    NULL |
| 1515765743 |    NULL |
| 1515765743 |    NULL |
| 1515765744 |    NULL |
+------------+---------+
```

**What's wrong with my code?**

```
UPDATE decayworld AS a
SET a.Destroy=(SELECT FLOOR (a.Created+RAND()*(864000-432000+1))+432000)
WHERE a.Destroy=(NULL)
;
```

Actually I got `0 rows are affected`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do `field = NULL`, instead use `field IS NULL`

Try bellow code:

```
UPDATE decayworld AS a
SET a.Destroy=(SELECT FLOOR (a.Created+RAND()*(864000-432000+1))+432000)
WHERE a.Destroy IS NULL;
```

If you want more info on using NULL values in mysql : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html

Comment: Perfect :) When the time has come I accept this as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL (an others), you need to use IS NULL rather than = NULL which will equate to false.

Comment: `= null` actually equates to `null`, not `false`, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for `is null`.

When the `Destroy` column is null, your condition becomes `null = null` which returns `null` - which is not true!

Try the below code:

```
select null = null; 
select null is null;
```